# I am trying to execute simple SQL code which executes after every 30 seconds

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

```
declare @timeToRun nvarchar(50);
declare @t1 int;

set @t1=10;
set @timeToRun = right(rtrim(CONVERT(VARCHAR(70), GETDATE(), 108)),2)

if @timeToRun = @t1 
begin
--   waitfor time @timeToRun
   begin
       print 'Hello';
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server code that needs to run repeatedly may better be done using a SQL Server Agent job. [Here is the documentation to create a SQL Server Agent job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-job?view=sql-server-2017). Briefly, the procedure to do this in SQL Server Management Studio is:

1. In the Object Explorer, click the plus sign to expand the server where you want to create a SQL Server Agent job.
2. Click the plus sign to expand SQL Server Agent.
3. Right-click the Jobs folder and select "New Job...".
4. In the New Job dialog box, on the General page, modify the general properties of the job.
5. On the Steps page, organize the job steps.
6. On the Schedules page, organize schedules for the job.
7. On the Alerts page, organize the alerts for the job.
8. On the Notifications page, set actions for Microsoft SQL Server Agent to perform when the job completes.
9. On the Targets page, manage the target servers for the job.
10. When finished, click OK.

Comment: In object explorer, Server agent is not found, i tried to start agent via sql server configuration and services.msc, but not success. find error in both methods.

Comment: SQL Server Agent is not available in the Express edition, perhaps that is why? If so, perhaps you can instead use the Windows Task Scheduler or write a Windows service to make a SQL query on a schedule.

Comment: yes, I am using express edition and that's why I am facing this problem. thank you Stephen Jennings.

Answer (score 0):

I find code which works properly, problem aries with SQL SERVER EXPRESS EDITION, it does not provides SQL AGENT, same query execute successfully with SQL SERVER STANDARD EDITION.